Expand $\sqrt{1-4x}$ into an infinite power series
I'm reading the book Math Girls. At one time (p. 131), a closed form was obtained for generating function $C(x)$ like below.
$$C(x)=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{2x}$$
To facilitate further deduction, the following replacement was performed without justification.
$$\begin{align}
\sqrt{1-4x}&=K_0+K_1x+K_2x^2+\cdots+K_nx^n+\cdots\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}K_kx^k
\end{align}$$
This replaced $\sqrt{1-4x}$ with another generating function $K(x)$. I wonder what has allowed this to be a valid replacement. Is it Taylor's theorem?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series

For $C(x)$ in particular look up Catalan numbers.

The on-site search engine thinks that we already have 292 questions that somewhat match with the buzzwords Catalan numbers generating function. Users younger than me were raised using search engines, and can undoubtedly refine that search better than I ever will. Happy diving!

@Lingxi Please change the sum index variable... $K_k$ is terrible notation!

The power series representation of $f(x)=\sqrt{1-4x}$ can be indeed obtained from Taylor's theorem. Keep in mind that this series representation will not be valid in the whole domain of $f$, but just on $]-1/4,1/4[$. In this case you can write
$$
\sqrt{1-4x} = \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} \dfrac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!} x^k.
$$

In general, a Taylor series does not converge to the original function. See, the classic example of $g(x) = e^{\frac{-1}{x^2}}$ for $x>0$ and $g(x) = 0$ for $x<0$.
For $f(x) := \sqrt{1-4x}$, we want to establish: $$ \sqrt{1-4x} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} K_k x^k, \text{ where } K_k = \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}. \tag{1}$$
By Taylors Theorem, we have:
$$\sqrt{1-4x} =  \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}x^k + R_n(x) \tag{2}$$
If $\lim_{n \to \infty} R_n(x) = 0$, then taking the limit as $n$ goes to infinity of both sides of equation $(2)$ gets us the desired result. However, $R_n(x)$ will not converge to zero for all values of $x$. We can find an expression for $R_n(x)$ on an open interval where $f(x)$ is $n+1$ times differentiable. Thus, we can restrict ourselves to the interval $\left(-\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4}\right)$. We can find where $R_n(x)$ will converge by examining its mean value form. If $x\in \left(-\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4}\right)$,
$$R_n(x) = \frac{f^{(n+1)}(c)}{(n+1)!}x^{n+1}, \text{ for some $c$ between $0$ and $x$.}$$
The rest boils down to finding a reasonable bound on the size of $f^{(n+1)}(x)$ for values of $x$ bounded away from the endpoints of the interval $\left(-\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4}\right)$. This can be done by explicitly computing $f^{(n+1)}(x)$.
